# pandas column list addition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column which consist of list of element of variable size and i have a other list name country=[A1,A2,A3] My Dataframe is like :

```
A  B
1  [A1,A2]
2  [A1,A2,A4,A5]
3  [A7,A8,A9]
```

what i want is the length of list present in column should not be greater than 3. If it is greater than 3. Then remove it last element if length is less than 3.then append those value from country_list which is not present in pandas column list.My final output should be like:

```
A   B
1   [A1,A2,A3]
2   [A1,A2,A4]
3   [A7,A8,A9]
```

Comment: you should show what you have tried allready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append not exist values and filter first 3 values by indexing with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
country=['A1','A2','A3']

def get_vals(x):
    if len(x) < 3:
        x += [y for y in country if y not in x]
    return x[:3]

df['B'] = df['B'].apply(get_vals)      
print (df)
   A             B
0  1  [A1, A2, A3]
1  2  [A1, A2, A4]
2  3  [A7, A8, A9]
```

First solution with loop:

```
out = []
for x in df['B']:
    if len(x) < 3:
        x += [y for y in country if y not in x]
    out.append(x[:3])

df['B'] = out
```

Comment: my column B value contains [5beab21c1e748515b8558972] (random row) it is giving me error: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @souravkhanna - so possible missing values in column?

Comment: @souravkhanna - If possible missing values how working first remove this rows by `df = df.dropna(subset=['B'])` before solution?

Comment: There was two null value . I replace null value with empty list and its works :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
country = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3, 4],
                 'B':[['A1', 'A2'], ['A1','A2','A4','A5'], ['A7','A8','A9'], ['A5']]})
df

    A   B
0   1   [A1, A2]
1   2   [A1, A2, A4, A5]
2   3   [A7, A8, A9]
3   4   [A5]

def new_list(x):
    if len(x)>=3:
        return x[:3]
    else:
        for val in country:
            if val not in x:
                x.append(val)
            if len(x)==3:
                return x

df['B'] = df['B'].apply(new_list)
df

    A      B                
0   1   [A1, A2, A3]
1   2   [A1, A2, A4]
2   3   [A7, A8, A9]
3   4   [A5, A1, A2]
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line it would look like:

```
df['B'] = [l[:3] if len(l)>= 3 else (l + [i for i in country if i not in l])[:3] for l in df['B']]
```

Comment: hmm, rewritten my solution?

Comment: @jezrael Didn't, and I really don't like apply, but +1 for speed :)

Comment: @jezrael also apply takes **129 µs** on my machine while this approach takes **15.1 µs**

Comment: ya, but it is wrong, because not filter `l + [i for i in country if i not in l]` for top3

Comment: @jezrael Excellent call, took too much for granted. Edited

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `[y for y in country if y not in x]` and `list(set(country).difference(x))`, you can use [numpy.setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
np.setdiff1d(x, country)
```

(couldn't comment due to reputation restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

you need [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[['A1','A2'],['A1','A2','A4','A5'],['A7','A8','A9']]})
def add_new(x):
    return x + list(set(country).difference(x))

df['B']=np.select([(df['B'].str.len()<3),(df['B'].str.len() > 3 )],[df['B'].apply(add_new),df['B'].str[:3]],default=df['B'])
```

or with a single line as @1b15 suggested,

```
df['B']=np.select([(df['B'].str.len()<3),(df['B'].str.len() > 3 )],[np.setdiff1d(df['B'],country),df['B'].str[:3]],default=df['B'])
```